# Xcode - implementing a method, also be implemented by its primary class

Tags: objective-c, pragma

I'm using Xcode 4.5. 
In my latest Xcode project, I have this warning pop up when i build/compile my program:

`Category is implementing a method which will also be implemented by its primary class`

This is my code that is causing the error:

```
 @implementation NSApplication (SDLApplication)
 - (void)terminate:(id)sender {
    SDL_Event event;
    event.type = SDL_QUIT;
    SDL_PushEvent(&event); }
 @end
```

I have made it so the compiler ignores (or skips over) the warning generate using `pragma code`.

So my code now looks like this:

```
 @implementation NSApplication (SDLApplication)

 #pragma clang diagnostic push
 #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wobjc-protocol-method-implementation"
 - (void)terminate:(id)sender{
   SDL_Event event;
   event.type = SDL_QUIT;
   SDL_PushEvent(&event);}
 #pragma clang diagnostic pop
 @end
```

Obviously it does the job and once built/compiled, no warning is generated.

My question is, is this a safe/ok way to suppress or ignore the warning in this way?

I read on some threads that using subclasses were advantageous, but there were many people fore and against using them in this way... I'd appreciate your thoughts :)

Comment: If you link the binary with `all_load`, then yes, it is safe. Whenever possible, you should prefer other methods, however, as this one is quite cryptic, and while it works, it isn't very maintainable for large projects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> "I read on some threads that using subclasses were advantageous..."

Using subclasses may be advantageous but that's not what you are doing here.

What you have done is implemented an `(SDLApplication)` [Objective-C Category](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW2) on `NSApplication`. In that category, you are overriding `NSApplication`'s `terminate:` method. In general, you should use categories only to add additional methods to an existing class, not to override existing methods, as that can have unpredictable results.

What you really should do is subclass `NSApplication` so that you can override `terminate:` properly:

```
@interface SDLApplication : NSApplication {

}

@end


@implementation

- (void)terminate:(id)sender {
   SDL_Event event;
   event.type = SDL_QUIT;
   SDL_PushEvent(&event);
   [super terminate:sender]; // this line is the key to assuring proper behavior
}

@end
```

The last step in your overridden `terminate:` method should be a call to `super`, so that the terminate method works as it should. (Using the keyword `super` in a category is not allowed; only the word `self`, which is why there's a need for subclassing).

Make sure you also change the value for the `NSPrincipalClass` key in your `Info.plist` file to be `SDLApplication` instead of `NSApplication`.

Comment: Yes i know my original code isn't using subclasses. I merely read somewhere that it was an alternative option to merely suppressing the warnings using `pragma`s. Having said that, i wasn't 100% sure how to implement a subclass in `C++` and this has been very helpful indeed :) Thanks for taking the time to explain this.

Answer (score 3):

## No.

Overriding (or re-implementing) methods, especially critical system methods like `-terminate:` in a category results in undefined behavior.  Obviously, quitting an application should not be a game of chance.  Subclass NSApplication and override `-terminate:` (with a call to super at the end), then specify it in the info.plist as the Principal Class.  `Pragma`s aren't warning fixers, they're merely suppressors.

Comment: It's actually well defined what happens when a method overrides an existing one with a protocol, so long as it is linked with `all_load`. There are many legitimate reasons to do this, mainly modifying frameworks that are 3rd party & not open sourced to fix bugs.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: What you described is called "monkey patching", also known as "duck punching" :) See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch

Comment: But I would assume that based on the above implementation (the calls to SDL), means that he's not in one of those situations.  All it would take is a subclass and an extra super call, not pragma'ing his way to obscurity and future bugs.

Comment: I agree. And the `pragma` code was merely to suppress the warning at the time. I planned to find advice on the correct why to deal with it with answers from this post. Thanks for the explanation.